# Can I set an entity relation with just the ID?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entity-relationship

I have a JPA (Hibernate) entity:

```
@Entity class Transaction {

  @ManyToOne
  private Room room;

}
```

When I create a new `Transaction`, I know the ID of the `Room` that it should refer to (but don't have a `Room` object). Can I somehow create and persist a `Transaction` with just this info, or do I really need to:

```
Room room = em.find(roomId, Room.class);
em.persist(new Transaction(room, ...));
```

Comment: I too have this requirement to avoid unnecessary database queries to fetch the child object purely for the purpose of setting it in a foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EntityManager.getReference()` to get a proxy of the related entity without accessing the database. This proxy is lazy-initialized and will be initialized only when you query anything other than the ID if the entity.

Comment: Yes, since asking the question I've learned that this is indeed the correct way

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32542366/4071001) to see an example.

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for! I think there are some questions that are thirsty for this answer.

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-manager-get-reference , this only avoids the round-trip to database for updates, not for delete or create operations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I found an alternate solution but may be its not a best practice.

Now since the mapping is depending on the **roomId** create a constructor **Room(Type roomId) and set that bean before you save Transaction bean**. So need to get the data from the DB. What hibernate cares about the Id that it needs to map the beans.

I have used this approach to get the data and I hope you don't want the **Room** to get updated when you update **Transaction**. So set the *insert,update properties of the mappings to false.*

Comment: I thought about that, but was worried that Hibernate would see the fake `Room` as not persisted yet. I'll try this.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom: Did you try this? or got any issues?