# Lazily loading an object in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, optimization, lazy-loading

Is there a way to load an object lazily (having only id loaded) with Hibernate?

I'm writing a synchronization code, which synchronizes a huge database. We are trying to do optimizations on it, and currently the bottleneck is hibernate loading lots of unneeded fields over a slow connection. For example:

```
Person p = createPersonFromOtherDbData(params);
Address a = loadAddressFromLocalDB(p.getAddressParams());
p.setAddress(a);
session.insert(p);
```

So basically, it would be enough to fetch an "id" of that "Address" object and put it into the new "Person" object. However, hibernate loads lots of unneeded fields (unneeded **in the context of synchronization** but needed in the rest of application) from Address object. Is there any way to optimize this part of code given that the session is stateless?

**Adeed:**

I believe this question is related to: [Can I set an entity relation with just the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847404/can-i-set-an-entity-relation-with-just-the-id) , however it also has no specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session.load()` does exactly what you want, and is used mainly to implement your use-case: if the address is not loaded in the session cache yet, then it simply returns an Address proxy wrapping the id.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I'm operating over a StatelessSession object, which does not provide a `load` method. Could it be that given that the session is stateless, I can just put a `new Address(id)` and it will work?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part about the stateless session. I have no experience with them. What happens when you try? I would assume that it works, given that it does work with normal sessions.

Comment: Ok, I have tried that (creating empty object with only id) and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `projection` to fetch particular field from the database. Here is one example :

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)
    .setProjection( Property.forName("name"))
    .list();
```

Comment: Yes I do, but the problem is that I can not use the fetched ID to create a relationship between newly created Person and old existing Address.

Comment: Yeah true. That's because you did mention Address Field in your Person Table, not address_id. So hibernate is going to search for Address's object, not its id. Hope I cleary stated my point.