# how to manage many-to-one jpa for save and find the data using DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two table with many-to-one relationship. Example is, I have Office table and Employee table. One Employee belong to one Office and one Office belong to many Employee.

**Office**

```
@Entity(name = "office")
@Table(name = "office", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Office {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "office_name", nullable = false)
    private String officeName;
}
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Table(name = "employee", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
    private String employeeName;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "office_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Office office;
}
```

**OfficeDto**

```
public class OfficeDto {

    private Long id;
    private String officeName;
}
```

**EmployeeDto**

```
public class EmployeeDto {

    private Long id;
    private String employeeName;
    private OfficeDto office;
}
```

With above way of defining the `entity` and the `DTO`, when I do `employee.findAll()`, the JSON result is also include the detail of the office data.

Is there any way that I could achieve (**objective**):

1. When do saving new `employee`, I just have to mention the `id` of the `office`.
2. When do `findAll` employee, I could choose whether I want to gove the `id` only or also with the entire object to the client.

Because, with current situation, I think I need to define two employee `DTO`. First one is contain the entire office data (like the code of `EmployeeDto`) and the second one is replace `private OfficeDto office` with `private int office`.

Comment: Add `@JsonIgnore` in place of `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})`. Then, in your JSON response of **Employee** you won't find **Office** data.   When you save a new Employee you have to assign a new Office to **office** property or find the existing Office by its id and assign it instead. To achieve your 2nd objective you will have to use **projections**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second problem you can solve by projection : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
Or just specific mapper to DTO, for mapping you can use mapstruct : http://mapstruct.org/documentation/installation/

For the first problem i found some answer in stack, but you need verify it : [JPA many-to-one relation - need to save only Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27930449/jpa-many-to-one-relation-need-to-save-only-id)