# Hibernate not fetching foreign key object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378345/13995601

In Product.class:

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long categoryId;
```

Category.class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "category_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "category_sequence", sequenceName = "category_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

```
        Product pr = productRepository.save(product);
        System.out.println(pr.getCategory()); // prints null
```

but, when I fetch Product, only category_id is populated and not category and I want the category field.
I used this approach in most places in my app, so it's important for me to understand what is the case.

Comment: If you're going to use `FetchType.EAGER` on the relationship field anyway, then why have a separate field for the `category_id`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I want to insert foreign key id (category_id) when creating Product instead of fetching Category first.

Comment: But then the entity you are trying to persist is inconsistent.  I guess you've annotated it well enough that the persistence provider will choose the correct source for the foreign key id, but inasmuch as you need at some point to fetch `Category`s in order to know about which ones exist in the first place, I'm not seeing how this is the right place to be looking for an optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         Product pr = productRepository.save(product);
>         System.out.println(pr.getCategory()); // prints null
> ```

Based on your comments on the question, I gather that you set only a category ID, not a `Category`, before persisting the `Product`.  In that case, it is unsurprising that "null" is printed.  Persisting a new entity with `save()` makes its existing state persistent.  There is no guarantee that its state will then be updated from the database, or, in particular, that relationships will be fetched.  Why would they be?  They were just saved.

I think you're probably doing yourself more harm than good by mapping both `category` and `categoryId`, but if you continue with that then you will need to manually refresh your product entities after you save them to ensure that the `Category` associated with their (new or possibly changed) `categoryId` is fetched.  Given the appropriate Hibernate `Session` as `sess`, that would be

```
        Product pr = productRepository.save(product);
        sess.refresh(pr);
        System.out.println(pr.getCategory()); // prints null
```

Or given the appropriate `EntityManager` as `em`, you could use `em.refresh(pr)` instead of `sess.refresh(pr)`.  It looks like you are using Spring Data, but its repository interfaces do not define refresh methods that you could use directly, nor do they provide means to access an underlying `Session` or `EntityManager`, so you'll have to sort that out.

Comment: Thank you. From what I've seen, the majority of articles online use a single-field approach (category in my case). However, I was just wondering if having to fetch an entity from the database only to save another has any impact on performance?

Comment: @european_2, with your two-field approach and trying to shortcut on setting the category, you definitely need `refresh()` to load the relationship, and that definitely will fetch all the way from the database.  If you just loaded a `Category` from a repository then you might get one that was loaded previously, and so save a round trip to the DB.  And you don't even have to go to the repository if you have the appropriate `Category` object hanging around from a previous load of that or an entity containing it.  This is what I mean by "more harm than good".

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you don't use lombok if you have complicated entities mapping in order for you to trace properly which ones are mapped to which. Don't forget the mandatory referencedColumnName when you join and foreign keys if there are any in your product class. You are joining it to your category table by id so in your category class, your id column name must be set to reference it properly.

-- edit

sample snippet:

Authorities.class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE,
    CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "authorities_fk"))
private User user;
```

User.class

```
@Id
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
```

Comment: This is all good advice, but it's not clear how it answers the question posed.

Comment: edited my post. have a look at how to properly map in hibernate when joining tables. might help.